# Constraints on Type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to constraint a generic type to only integral type?

In example, if I have a method

```
T[] sort<T>(T[] data) where : T ... {}
```

what would I put as constraint if I wanted to ensure the parameter will be some sort of integral type?

I have tryed looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=VS.80).aspx) however it does not seem to mention anything about constraining and primitive types.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, no can do. Also this has been asked before here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  I asked this question before with VB.Net.

[Generic Classes (T) - Specifying from a Range of Types VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358416/generic-classes-t-specifying-from-a-range-of-types-vb-net)

As quoted from the page above:
*Also, you mentioned constraining to numerics, but I don't think you can constrain to just that. You can however constrain to just primitive types (on the stack) and not allow objects (on the heap) by doing this: Public Structure Statistic(Of t As {Structure, IComparable}).*

Answer (score 0):

The same technique -- constraining generic types to be (in C#) struct and IComparable, came up as an answer to detecting boxed values for performance.

[How to test whether a value is boxed in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806898/how-to-test-whether-a-value-is-boxed-in-c-net)