# Comparing boxed values does not behave as expected

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare objects within two different `Dictionary<string,object>` (to find differences in a versioned repository.

The dictionary can contains any serialize type, either value-type or reference-type.

I loop on all keys to perform the comparison. Because of the value type boxing, I implemented a small utility method [found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209126/588868) :

```
private static bool AreValueEquals(object o1, object o2)
{
    return (o1 != null && o1.GetType().IsValueType)
        ? o1.Equals(o2)
        : o1 == o2;
}
```

This method is used in my main method like this:

```
private static List<string> GetDifferent(Dictionary<string, object> currentValues, Dictionary<string, object> previousValues)
{
    var changed = from fieldName in currentValues.Keys.Union(previousValues.Keys).Distinct()
                  let currentVal = GetIfExists(currentValues, fieldName)
                  let previousVal = GetIfExists(previousValues, fieldName)
                  where !AreValueEquals(currentVal, previousVal)
                  select fieldName;
    return changed.ToList();
}
private static object GetIfExists(Dictionary<string, object> values, string fieldName)
{
    return values.ContainsKey(fieldName) ? values[fieldName] : null;
}
```

While the `AreValueEquals` method works as expected [on my test case (dotnetfiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4dKAl3), at **runtime**, I get unexpected result:

[image: result]

I don't understand this result. Is my implementation correct? How to fix?

Comment: Don't roll your own, the framework provides a [`Comparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comparer for this purpose.  If you can't use that, please explain your **unique** requirement.  But this is what the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` itself uses.

Comment: I don't know the type at compile time... only at runtime. I cannot use this generic class, isn't it?

Comment: It implements the non-generic `IComparer` interface.  You need a little reflection (or the `dynamic` keyword) to get the right comparer.

Comment: Actually, just `bool AreValueEquals(dynamic o1, dynamic o2)
{
    return o1 == o2;
}` might be your easiest approach.

Comment: Just tried `Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(o1,o2)==0` in my test case... Surprisingly, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: oops, I should have said [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx) not `Comparer<T>.Default`

Comment: I don't see why you would need that utility method. Static `object.Equals` would work just fine for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is a reference type.

I don't know how you are creating those strings but they a re probably represented as 2 different instances of string object.

In you method you aare doing a `==` on 2 objects. This will by default check only if they are the same references.

Why not use Generics and use the Comparer.Default or just use the Equals() with a null check considering your are boxing?

```
    object a = "d";
    object b = new String(new []{'d'});

    Console.Write("a == b: ");

    Console.WriteLine(a == b);

    Console.WriteLine("AreValueEquals: " + AreValueEquals(a,b));

    Console.WriteLine("Equals: " + a.Equals(b));
```

Gives:

```
a == b: False
AreValueEquals: False
Equals: True
```

Confirming the intern:

```
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nComparing 2 constants\r\n");

    object c = "d";

    Console.Write("a == c: ");

    Console.WriteLine(a == c);

    Console.WriteLine("AreValueEquals: " + AreValueEquals(a,c));

    Console.WriteLine("Equals: " + a.Equals(c));
```

Gives:

```
Comparing 2 constants

a == c: True
AreValueEquals: True
Equals: True
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3nH5Z)

Comment: if confirm your hypothesis... using the debugger, I can see that `o1 == o2` is false with strings. I actually wonder how this could have worked on .Net fiddled

Comment: I have added fiddle + code from it. In the .net fiddle you were probably creating 2 strings by using constants. Compiler is smart enough to know that they are the same thing, and will intern it, and use the same interned reference.

Comment: Why not just use Equals?

Comment: if I wrote "x" using `new string((char)('y' -1),1)`, the comparison is false (and confirm the intern behavior)

Comment: *using Equals*? do you mean `if(o1 == null && o2==null) return true; if(o1 != null) return o1.Equals(o2);  return false;` ?

Comment: Yep. The reason this often doesn't work is if you use value types. As you cannot check a value type for null. But as you are boxing already (very expensive) you can do the check you provided.

Comment: Finally, you helped me to understand the root of my issue (string comparison, hidden by my test case which interned the constants). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the GetDifferent method to what I think you are after:

```
private static List<string> GetDifferent(Dictionary<string, object> currentValues, Dictionary<string, object> previousValues)
{
    var changed = currentValues
                  .Where(k => previousValues.Any(p => p.Key == k.Key && !AreValueEquals(k.Value, p.Value)))
                  .Select(k => k.Key);
    return changed.ToList();
}
```

See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JZ6v6a

Comment: No, i actually compare the value. Look at my screenshot, the type and values are the string value.

Comment: You're right. I've confirmed this by reproducing your code in another fiddle. Here it is if anyone wants to use it to help https://dotnetfiddle.net/ilfKFy

Comment: Is there any difference with my code (I can't see any)

Comment: No I took the change I added above out so it is the same as your OP

Comment: See my updates to my original post, I think this is what you are looking for