# What is the purpose of a class statement or specifying a type on a class?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, oop

I have recently come across some code where a class is written specifying a type:

```
  public class MyClass<T>
   {

   }
```

OR

```
Public Class MyClass(Of T)

End Class
```

I don't understand the purpose?

I read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa0hwf23.aspx) explanations of a class statement but still not quite sure why this would be used?

Anyone with a good explanation?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Just a one hint to you That's called Template in C++ and generics in Java and c#. I would suggest you to have some tutorial on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358416/generic-classes-t-specifying-from-a-range-of-types-vb-net

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: You can't compare C++ Templates and Generics in Java and C#. They might look the same but they do work completly different. You have specialication, partial specialication and so on.  Detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i

Comment: @ckruczek Thanks for the information but here I was just meant that these sort of things refer to these terminology rather than in depth thing that run-time does for us differently for various programming languages.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: Agreed on that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well thats called [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). The meaning of such kind of class is,that you can provide some typeinformation when instantiating the class. A very popular example is the class [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Where you can specify the type that is beeing saved into the list. Example:

`List<int> ints = new List<int>();
List<String> strings = new List<String>;`